# empty xml value in node.js with xml-reader and map children

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I'm not able to get value of parameters like aldScanningInterval = 30 sec

Here is the sample_file.xml:

```
<raml><cmData>
<managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.eqm:APEQM" distName="MRBTS-Template/EQM-1/APEQM-1" version="EQM21A_2012_002" operation="create">
  <p name="aldScanningInterval">30 sec</p>
  <p name="berMajorAlarmThreshold">-12</p>
  <p name="berMinorAlarmThreshold">-13</p>
</managedObject>
```

And this is the code:

```
const XmlReader = require('xml-reader');
const xml = fs.readFileSync("./publish/DATA/A2G/templates/sample_file.xml", "utf8");

const xmlr = XmlReader.parseSync(xml);

const xmlQuery = require('xml-query');

xmlQuery(xmlr).children().children().map(node => console.log(node.attributes.distName + "\n Params:\n  " + node.children.map(child => child.attributes.name + "=" + child.value + "\n")));
```

What I get in console is:

```
Okt 31 13:30:54 S5-VPN a2gc[2835315]: MRBTS-Template/EQM-1/APEQM-1
Okt 31 13:30:54 S5-VPN a2gc[2835315]:  Params:
Okt 31 13:30:54 S5-VPN a2gc[2835315]:   aldScanningInterval=
Okt 31 13:30:54 S5-VPN a2gc[2835315]: ,berMajorAlarmThreshold=
Okt 31 13:30:54 S5-VPN a2gc[2835315]: ,berMinorAlarmThreshold=
```

The value is not coming. Why? I tried also with .text and becomes undefined.

This is what comes from:

```
xmlQuery(xmlr).children().children().map(node => console.log(node.children));

Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]: [ { name: 'p',
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:     type: 'element',
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:     value: '',
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:     parent:
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:      { name: 'managedObject',
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:        type: 'element',
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:        value: '',
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:        parent: [Object],
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:        attributes: [Object],
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:        children: [Circular] },
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:     attributes: { name:    'aldScanningInterval' },
Okt 31 13:41:47 S5-VPN a2gc[2838984]:     children: [ [Object] ] },
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

solved using below function

```
 xmlQuery(child).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try camaro, it's easy to reformat the input xml

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

async function main() {
        const xml = `
<raml><cmData>
<managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.eqm:APEQM" distName="MRBTS-Template/EQM-1/APEQM-1" version="EQM21A_2012_002" operation="create">
  <p name="aldScanningInterval">30 sec</p>
  <p name="berMajorAlarmThreshold">-12</p>
  <p name="berMinorAlarmThreshold">-13</p>
</managedObject>
</cmData>
</raml>
`
        const template = {
                data: ['raml/cmData/managedObject/p', {
                        key: '@name',
                        value: '.'
                        }
                ]
        }
        const result = await transform(xml, template)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
}

main()
```

output

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "aldScanningInterval",
      "value": "30 sec"
    },
    {
      "key": "berMajorAlarmThreshold",
      "value": "-12"
    },
    {
      "key": "berMinorAlarmThreshold",
      "value": "-13"
    }
  ]
}
```